# Show news from selected date using url GET parameter

Tags: typo3, tx-news

How we can show the news from selected date like `index.php?id=6&dateselected=13.04.2019`

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.timeRestriction= {GP:dateselected} 
plugin.tx_news.settings.timeRestrictionHigh= {GP:dateselected} +24 hour
```

not working but this code working

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.timeRestriction= 13.04.2019  
plugin.tx_news.settings.timeRestrictionHigh= 13.04.2019 +24 hour
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `plugin.tx_news.settings.timeRestriction= {GP:dateselected}`, or something similar, you need `stdWrap` functionality.

Then you need: `plugin.tx_news.settings.timeRestriction.insertData = 1`

Or you could use `plugin.tx_news.settings.timeRestriction.data`

You need to activate the `stdWrap` for these fields:

```
plugin.tx_news {
    settings {
        useStdWrap = timeRestriction,timeRestrictionHigh

        timeRestriction.data = GP:dateselected

        timeRestrictionHigh = {GP:dateselected} + 24hour
        timeRestrictionHigh.stdWrap.insertData = 1
    }
}
```